# Stop Running Macro other than ESC / Command +

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2016

How do I stop a running macro in Mac Excel 2016 (version 15)?

I tried:
Command + .
Esc
Esc x2

`Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt`, doesn't make any difference.

Comment: it is possible that your code is super busy and does not respond to key presses. if you have any loops where a lot of data is being handled, or it is waiting for data to be available, insert `doevents`  command in that loop.  ... the VBA code will briefly stop its execution and allow system events (like keypresses) to be handled.

Comment: Thanks for the help jsotola, but I cannot stop it even when it's simply displaying a count down in the status bar, so it is unlikely.

Comment: web search yields `Command + .` as the `break` keyboard sequence and also `esc esc`, which you already tried. so it appears that the code is just plain busy.

Comment: try `ctrl esc` `ctrl esc`

Comment: Hey jsotola DoEvents actually does the job! Esc still doesn't stop the execution, but command + . works now! Thank you so much! Weirdly Ctrl Esc also doesn't do anything

Comment: `DoEvents` command is very important to include if you have any kind of a loop that waits for something that may never arrive (like in web scraping). otherwise Excel locks up and you have to kill the Excel process.

Comment: also, with the `DoEvents` in the code, you can set a breakpoint, while the code is running, by clicking in the gray sidebar to the left of the command on which you want set the breakpoint

Comment: @DennisLau Have you tried `ctrl + pause break`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip jsotola, never knew this before, thanks!

Comment: @dwirony Mac doesn't have a separate pause break key mapping as far as I know so I guess I am sticking with DoEvents and Command + . as suggested by jsotola. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Never use `DoEvents()` - it can make your code buggy and very difficult to then debug.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by jsotola, use DoEvents to have Excel handle keypress, then **hold** Command + . to interrupt it.

Thanks for the help jsotola!

Comment: Never use `DoEvents()` - it can make your code buggy and very difficult to then debug.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, thanks for chiming in. What would be your preferred way of doing this?

Comment: @DennisLau Yes. You have. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are on VBA/ExcelVBA window and then Try below steps:

**Step 1-- Menu bar -> Run -> Reset**

**Step 2-- Menu bar -> Run -> Break**